# How to send web request from a Chrome app

Tags: sockets, cors, google-chrome-app

A Chrome app can connect to server using socket ([chrome.sockets.tcp](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp#method-send)). Is there any way to do cross domain request (like HTTPXmlRequest) to arbitrary domains. I do not want to use chrome extension due to security concern. There is also [WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), but again, cannot receive respond data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a permission in the `manifest.json` for all domains you will be XHR'ing to. If you don't know beforehand which domains, you can add a permission for any url:

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
```

Comment: Host permissions is only available for extension, not for app.

Comment: @KyawTun ..and: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions -- I'm pretty sure that wildcard is supported.  Certainly explicit hosts are.  Let me know if <all_urls> doesn't work for you, that would be a bug.

Comment: My understanding is Chrome app cannot use host permission.

Comment: "My understanding is Chrome app cannot use host permission." It's very inexpensive to test this understanding, isn't it?

Comment: You won't be allowed to set "unsafe" headers like User-Agent, but you'll be able to make cross domain requests at will.